# How to convert _bn back to PublicKey in JS?

Tags: javascript, publickey

I have this dict in JS, I want to convert it to PublicKey.

```
const account = {
        "_bn": {
          "negative": 0,
          "words": [
            37883239,
            7439402,
            52491380,
            11153292,
            7903486,
            65863299,
            41062795,
            11403443,
            13257012,
            36844946,
            320410,
            0
          ],
          "length": 11,
          "red": null
        }
      }
```

I have tried with `new PublicKey(account)` and `new PublicKey(account.Tostring())` without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a strange case, but you could recreate the `BN` using this dict, and then recreate the `PublicKey`, ie:

```
const pubkeyJson = {}; // put your JSON in here
const num = new BN(0); // just create something
num.words = pubkeyJson._bn.words;
num.length = pubkeyJson._bn.length;
num.red = pubkeyJson._bn.red;
num.negative = pubkeyJson._bn.negative;
const publicKey = new PublicKey(num);
```

I'm using the BN constructor reference at https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/blob/master/lib/bn.js#L21